# iPhone Development - Access Apple's default Icon images

Tags: iphone, uiimage, toolbars

Can i get system provided icons/images in a UIImage. I'm referring to the icons/images referenced [here](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/SystemProvided/SystemProvided.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH15-SW11).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not through the API.  You can, however, provide your own images form the great icons set: [Glyphish](http://www.glyphish.com/)